# How to train a big model with relatively large batch size on a single GPU using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a very big model which cannot be trained on a single GPU with batch size 64 due to out of memory error. Someone suggest that I use smaller batch size. However, if I decrease my batch size, the accuracy drops down. One of the solutions is just feeding half of the current batch, storing the gradients and then feeding the remaining. This can be done explicitly by using `compute_gradients` and `apply_gradients`. But it is relatively inconvenient (it is OK if a concise implementation exists). So I wonder if there is any nicer solutions (or concise implementation) to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What isn't concise about `computer_gradients` and `apply_gradients`?

Comment: What I mean is that it is a bit inconvenient if I implement aggregate gradients outside of tensorflow (using numpy to calculate the mean), at least it will loss some performance. It would be great if I can calculate the gradients by half of a batch and then the remaining using Tensorflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider looking into this: https://github.com/openai/gradient-checkpointing.

There has been a lot of research lately on making backprop more memory efficient at the expense of additional forward passes. This is a very recent implementation of one such scheme for TensorFlow.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I need.